# Accessing HDFS with java from Windows

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I have a Cloudera Hadoop installation, and I would like to write a Java program to read/write from the file system, from a Windows machine.  Should this be possible?

My program is very simple:

```
public class HadoopReader {
static {
    URL.setURLStreamHandlerFactory(new FsUrlStreamHandlerFactory());
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("okay");
    InputStream in = null;
    try {
        in = new URL("hdfs://HOST/PATH").openStream();
        IOUtils.copyBytes(in, System.out, 4096, false);
    } finally {
        IOUtils.closeStream(in);
    }
}
}
```

but I am getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.net.URLStreamHandler.parseURL(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.file.Handler.parseURL(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.URLClassPath$FileLoader.getResource(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.URLClassPath$FileLoader.findResource(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.URLClassPath$1.next(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.URLClassPath$1.hasMoreElements(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$3$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$3.next(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$3.hasMoreElements(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.CompoundEnumeration.next(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.CompoundEnumeration.hasMoreElements(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.hasNext(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.hasNext(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.loadFileSystems(FileSystem.java:2117)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2128)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FsUrlStreamHandlerFactory.createURLStreamHandler(FsUrlStreamHandlerFactory.java:66)
...
```

I am using the jars from the 'source' download for Cloudera 4 (previously, I had downloaded an old version of Hadoop, and while the URL seemed to parse fine, there was a version mis-match)

Comment: I tried "hdfs://HOSTNAME/test.txt"... where HOSTNAME was the name of the master node

Comment: run this command: hadoop fs -test -e hdfs://HOSTNAME/test.txt and tell us the output

Comment: On one of the actual nodes, If I do:
 "hadoop fs -ls /"
I get:

"-rw-r--r--   3 root  supergroup       2093 2012-08-10 11:21 /WordCount.java"
(and others)

and "hadoop fs -ls -test -e /WordCount.java"
returns no output at all

Comment: Why don't you use the simple `FileSystem` class?

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the hadoop FileSystem class. IOUtils has nothing to do with hadoop and what you are doing cannot work.

Take a look at this method [Path.getFileSystem](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.20.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/Path.html#getFileSystem%28org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration%29)

Use a hadoop core-site.xml with the hdfs filesystem url that you are connecting to. Ideally, take a copy of this xml from the Namenode of the hdfs itself. Put it in your classpath, and you are good to go with all the hdfs client apis.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    confVirtual.set("fs.default.name", "hdfs://ip:port");
    confVirtual.set("mapred.job.tracker", "hdfs://ip:port");
    FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
```

after accessing to your HDFS cluster this way , you can do read/write operation through FSDataOutputStream/FSDataInputStream class.